# Google Maps - synchronize zoom/position of multiple maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a standard way to synchronize the position and zoom of two Google maps in the same page.

The idea is too have both besides, [two maps](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/06/creating-synchronized-view-of-two-maps.html). It should work with mouse zoom and recenter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try this, on your drag event set the 2nd maps' center by taking it from the first map

```
map2.setCenter(map1.getCenter());
```

you can do the same with zoom

```
map2.setZoom(map1.getZoom());
```

working fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mervinsamy/w076uaL4/

```js
var map1, map2;
var listener1;
var listener2;

function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8120918, -117.9211629),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  };
  var mapOptions2 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.8120918, -117.9211629),
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  };

  map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), mapOptions);
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), mapOptions2);


  map1.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener2);
    listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(map1, 'bounds_changed', (function() {
      map2.setCenter(map1.getCenter());
      map2.setZoom(map1.getZoom());
    }));
  });


  map2.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
    listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'bounds_changed', (function() {
      map1.setCenter(map2.getCenter());
      map1.setZoom(map2.getZoom());
    }));
  });


}
```

```css
#map1,
#map2 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map1">
</div>


<div id="map2"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmj6gxqgx_9AUOSJoXY6f7q2WrsexIlqE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: works, thanks. Why are you adding/removing the listeners on mouseover ?

Comment: actually you need to put the activation listener in the div, in the map it's strange as the manual zoom won't work 9

Comment: We changed a bit. Pay attention that mouseout is triggered when you hover over the zoom buttons (I'm using the underlying div instead)

Comment: Great, Solution works! but it is buggy. Event listeners keep firing bound change events which are caused by one another. This is an endless process. I could work around that by simply assigning the zoom and center of each map to a variable and, check if it has changed inside the bounds_changed event before setting the center and zoom of the other map. The problem is a bit similar to busy waiting commonly seen in concurrency control. And the solution follows the idea of semaphores.